# Django manage.py runserver doesn't open browser

Tags: django

I am starting Django with The Django book, and I got stuck while trying to visit 127.0.0.1:8000 with run server: it doesn't open any page!

What I did is:

```
python manage.py runserver 8000
```

and I got this:

```
Django version 1.6.8, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Everything seems to be right, but nothing is open in my browser (Google Chrome).

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Why do you think that running the server should open your browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django did not open your browser by default, you should do it yourself by open it and visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

If you use IDE like Pycharm, you can config it by check the `Run browser` to open it each time you restart.