# Prevent PyCharm from opening the browser/new tab on run

Tags: python, django, browser

I found a number of people who want PyCharm to open the browser/a new tab every time you click run.

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206590705-How-do-I-setup-Run-Debug-Config-to-open-browser-automatically-for-Flask-
- [Django manage.py runserver doesn't open browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267513/django-manage-py-runserver-doesnt-open-browser)

Well, I click `run` often and already have the tabs open I need. It's quite frustrating to have to close the new ones, and I want to turn it off. I have looked thru all the menus and I can't find the `Run browser` setting some people talk about.

I also tried disabling all Django support for browsers in Settings -> Tools -> Browsers, but this made no difference.

Versions:

- PyCharm 2017.1.1
- Python 3.5.x
- Django 1.10

Comment: edit run configurations(right next to the play button at the top of the editor) and uncheck the box that says open new window on run ....

Comment: Good find! PyCharm UI is a mess. Can you add this as an answer?

Comment: the default behaviour is to not open a new window... so you must have explicitly set it at some point... where would you have expected to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit run configurations(right next to the play button at the top of the editor) and uncheck the box that says open new window on run .... – @Joran Beasley
P/s: Just comment again.

Comment: what about pycharm 2021.2.1?

Answer (score 3):

For version 2018.3

1. Go to  File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console.
2. Check the option Use existing console for "Run with Python console".

Comment: for mac its similar:  pycharm | preferences... | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console -> Check the option Use existing console for "Run with Python console"

Answer (score 1):

**2018** :
Edit run configurations (at the left to the play button at the top of the editor, click on the list of configuration then edit configurations) and **check** the box that reads **single instance only**

Comment: what about pycharm 2021.2.1?