# Pycharm 2023 Community Edition opening an already open tab when debugging

Tags: pycharm

I'm using Pycharm 2023.2.1 Community Edition (on Windows 10 Enterprise) to create python scripts.
One extremely disturbing issue I keep facing is the following.
Say I have a python script with a main.py file as well as a second python file called data.py (in reality most of my python projects have 20+ python files).
I have both main.py and data.py open in my Pycharm. I select a debug row in data.py.
Then I run the debugger and when it gets to the row in data.py that it needs to debug it opens up another tab called ...\data.py causing the same python file to be opened twice.
I read [Prevent PyCharm from opening the browser/new tab on run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320243/prevent-pycharm-from-opening-the-browser-new-tab-on-run) but the "Run with Python console" doesn't fix the problem (one proposed solution there) and I can't locate "single instance only" solution proposed by another user. Another user suggested to uncheck "open new window on run" but this option doesn't seem to be available in my Pycharm version.
I read https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206602465-Debugger-opens-new-instance-of-code-file-in-editor and it seems other users in 2022 have also the same issue but I can't see a working solution.
Then, I read here https://www.reddit.com/r/pycharm/comments/m7njrk/everytime_i_try_to_run_my_code_on_debug_it_opens/ a user fixed it by removing empty spaced in the project directory but that's not my case.
Does anyone have a clue of how I could fix this problem? Thank you

Comment: Try the 2 options in settings -> advanced settings -> editor tabs...